# Armstrong Theorem 1.1

Tags: general-topology

The book "Basic Topology" by Armstrong has a section on Euler's Polyhedra formula,

he specifically states:

> Euler's Theorem let $P$ be a polyhedra which satisfies:
>
> > a. Any two vertices of $P$ can be connected by a chain of edges
> >
> > b. Any loop on $P$ which is made up of straight line segments (not necessarily edges) separates $P$ into $2$ pieces.
>
> Then $v - e + f = 2$.

So I was toying around with polyhedra and I came up with the following example, consider 2 tetrahedra $T_1, T_2$. Connect at a point, call this structure $G$.  Then if one applies Euler's formula to this they get $(4+3) - (6+6) + (4+4) = 3$, but every pair of vertices is edge connected, so the only conclusion is that there is a loop on the surface of $G$, which doesn't separate $G$ into 2 parts.

But I am having trouble finding such a loop intuitively, so I decided to try to fill in some details.

We consider a loop $l$ on the surface of $G$ as a connected non self intersecting curve. now we need to make a notion of seperation, the idea I had was to look at finding a surface of minimal surface area $S$ that has the loop $l$ as its  boundary. (This hopefully gets close to the notion of "slicing" along a loop)

One can then look at $N_\epsilon(S)$ which is to take the surface of $S$ and at each point form an $\epsilon$ sized ball around it.

Then the claim is that for sufficiently small $\epsilon$

$$ G -  N_\epsilon(S) $$

has 2 connected components.

So given this definition, I wanted to try to apply it to the $G$ I constructed but that is starting to get a little messy, so I wanted to call for some backup and ask if theres an obvious way to find the loop.

Comment: I also don't see a non-separating loop for $G$. Are you sure that it satisfies the definition of a polyhedron? On the other hand, there exist a loop separating the surface of $G$ into $3$ pieces.

Comment: @alex ravsky, a formal definition isn't given yet in the book but I see your example a loop on both halfs passing through the point at which the tetrahedra meet

Comment: So I think that's the counter example